# Facebook browser does not request access to the microphone

Tags: javascript, facebook, html5-audio, web-audio-api, microphone

I encountered such a problem: I have a microphone recording on my site. In chrome in mobile and desktop, he requests access to the microphone. But in the Facebook browser - no. I use web audio api, more precisely by calling 
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true, video: false})`. In the normal browser it produces: `[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved" [[PromiseValue]]: MediaStream`, on the Facebook browser `[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending" [[PromiseValue]]: undefined`. If anything, the Facebook browser user agent is: `Mozilla / 5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Redmi Note 4 Build / NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version / 4.0 Chrome / 80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari / 537.36 [FB_IAB / FB4A; FBAV / 262.0.0.34.117;]`. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in-app browsers do often block features which would be available in the standalone browser on the same device. Lee Martin wrote an article about that problem almost 2 years ago but I think nothing has changed since then.

https://medium.com/@leemartin/in-app-browsers-i-forgive-thee-not-f87b25f9418e